# Data relationships and filters

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, email-studio

When building a filtered data extension X, based on a data extension A with data relationships (A to B and B to C).
We can easily filter A on a field in B. We can also filter B on a field in C. We can also see fields in C, when filtering A. But using them as conditions in our filter, always returns 0 rows. Even though we can repeat same filtering using a query, and get a number of rows returned.

Shouldn't this be possible? We have contacted SFMC support, and can't get a clear answer back from them.

Comment: Why use Filters and Relationships?  A Query Activity would be a better (and more explicit) option -- especially since you're using Data Extensions.

Comment: Point taken - and this would also be my preferred approach. However, I am building this solution for a client, and they would prefer using filters, since this is more intuitive than queries.

Comment: It was a documented feature (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_multi_join_filters_scenario.htm&type=5) - wonder if it somehow lost functionality with the 'Enhanced' update?

Comment: I would also have expected it to work as per documentation. However my few attempts so far have been fruitless.

Answer (score 2):

This may seem anecdotal but I have seen on more than one occasion that Marketing Cloud has a very hard time with multiple exclusions and every time I split it apart to filter one thing at a time, it manages to do it better. I will mention I've seen this happen more frequently with Queries than with Filtered DE's but the same logic looks like it applies. Can you try spreading them out?